# Cant find the database driver for MediaWiki during installing

Tags: php, mysql, database, compilation, mediawiki

MYSQL and apache server are already installed on my server.
But still I encountered these problem.
I dont understand the terms to compile php with --with-mysql
Where should i compile? i am using window server.
or how to install the mysql.so module??

> Checking environment...
>
> Please include all of the lines below
>   when reporting installation problems.
>   PHP 5.2.14 installed Could not find a
>   suitable database driver! For MySQL,
>   compile PHP using --with-mysql, or
>   install the mysql.so module For
>   PostgreSQL, compile PHP using
>   --with-pgsql, or install the pgsql.so module For SQLite, compile PHP using
>   --with-pdo_sqlite, or install the pdo_sqlite.so module For MSSQL,
>   compile PHP using
>   --with-mssql_not_ready, or install the mssql_not_ready.so module For DB2,
>   compile PHP using --with-ibm_db2, or
>   install the ibm_db2.so module For
>   Oracle, compile PHP using --with-oci8,
>   or install the oci8.so module

Comment: Suggest this is placed on serverfault.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in /php_install_dir/extensions. There should be a file named "php_mysql.dll". If so, enable it in php.ini. If not, download the dll, copy it to the extension dir and enable in php.ini. Remember to restart Apache.

See [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.extensions.php) for more info (make sure you read the comments).

Answer (score 1):

For PHP: 5.6.10 and MySQL: 5.0.24a

1. Go to the root folder of PHP installation
2. Find a file called php.ini-production
3. Save the file as php.ini
4. Edit the file and uncomment the following contents

;extension=php_mysqli.dll
;extension_dir = "ext"

and replace it with,

extension= php_mysqli.dll
extension_dir = "D:\Programs\php\ext”

Comment: In my php.ini, it was "extension= php_mysqli" and extension_dir = "ext”, but close enough. Your advice got me past this error.

Answer (score 0):

Changed this in php.ini. Shouldn't the installer have done this for a Windows installation?

```
; enable_dl = Off

; CHANGED - This is necessary to enable dynamic loading of Windows .dll modules

; The immediate problem was that PHP could not find a database driver for MySQL

enable_dl = On
```

Comment: "does NOT work properly in multithreaded servers, such as IIS or Zeus, and is automatically disabled on them"